# How to install plugin-export-default-from to Babel in react project

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, ecmascript-2017

I have been getting the following error constantly throughout this process

```
SyntaxError: /Users/user1/npmprojects/experiments/test-reactstrap0/src/components/index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'exportDefaultFrom' isn't currently enabled (15:8):

  13 | export * from './ListItems';
  14 | 
> 15 | export FormField from './FormField';
```

First I install the plugin: `yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from --save-dev`

I have also tried installing `yarn add babel-preset-stage-1 --save-dev`

I have tried adding a .babelrc file with the contents

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from"
  ]
}
```

I have tried adding the following to my package.json

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-1",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue in Babel about it: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7293

Looks like you'd additionally need to install `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from` plugin, but not 100% sure, better read through the issue discussion and try the proposed workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

## You can put the configuration in your `babelrc.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from"
  ]
}
```

### Tools such as `babel` or `babel-loader` for `Webpack` will pick up the configuration from here.

Good Luck...

Comment: doesn't seem to work. Have you tested this?

Comment: Hi @Sisir, yes it worked back then when I used this in one of my projects.